# How do I mount .cue file?

Tags: 10.10, mount

I have a cd image that is not a .iso but a .cue. I cannot mount it. I use ubuntu 10.10 64 bits, and I've tried a lot of programs. furiosmout just says it is not a image file, and it just didn't work. I found a program (acetone) that can convert .cue in .iso, but it says I need other packages (that I could not come to). I was looking for an easy way. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a .bin file to accompany the .cue file?

Comment: yeah. But it's at home, so just a little latter I'm gonna try the solution.

Answer (score 66):

Typically a .cue file will be accompanied by a .bin file that contains the actual image data. If you'd like to convert it to the .iso format, the [Iso9660 Analyzer Tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/iat.1.html) (`apt-get install iat`) should do the trick:

```
iat --iso --input=my_image.bin --output=my_new_image.iso
```

Comment: I had to write `iat --input=my_image.bin --output=my_new_image.iso --iso` for the command to work.

Comment: Seems like the command line format has changed, I had to use: 
`iat my_image.bin > my_new_image.iso` (version v0.1.3)

Answer (score 30):

This has been bothering me in the past and I never did find a solution. I set out for an answer and [found it on a whim](http://maketecheasier.com/mount-iso-bin-and-cue-files-from-nautilus/2009/05/23); these instructions are derived from the script on that site.

You'll need the .bin file that should be accompanying the .cue file. Note the file sizes: the .bin is likely several hundred MB, while the .cue is probably less than one KB. If you have a large .cue file, it's possible it's named incorrectly, so it doesn't hurt to try this anyway:

1. Install `fuseiso` (`sudo apt-get install fuseiso`)
2. Run `fuseiso -p image_file.bin /path/to/mount`, and you should see the mount point fill up with files. This can be run as a normal user, and the directory doesn't have to exist.
3. When finished, run `fusermount -u /path/to/mount` to unmount and remove the directory `fuseiso` created.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I tried it and got errors for an audio CD .bin/cue, which was created by 'brasero' .. This is from `info fuseiso`: *"One major limitation of .BIN images is that fuseiso does not handle .CUE files in any way, and thus can work with only the first track of .BIN images."*

Comment: I also tried to mount a .bin created by brasero, and get `init: wrong standard identifier in volume descriptor 0, skipping..`. So it looks like fuseiso it doesn't work with brasero's .bin format.

Answer (score 22):

And also **bchunk** can do the same trick as **iat**:

```
bchunk IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue ANYNAME.iso
```

Comment: This seems to be more mainstream than iat

Answer (score 16):

The best way is to use [cdemu](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net/); I regularly use this utility for mounting bin/cue pairs. The program doesn't seem to be in the repositories, but there is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~cdemu/+archive/ppa) available at Launchpad; you can install it with these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdemu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcdemu cdemu-client
```

Just a simple `sudo apt-get install cdemu`, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76346/apps-capable-of-mounting-unmounting-cd-dvd-images-with-multi-sector-or-protected), won't work for this ppa. More information on ppas and how to use them is [available here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

As outlined in the man page, and reiterated [in this useful article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CDemu), it is simple to use. You can either use the `gcdemu` gui or issue `cdemu` commands in terminal.

Just specify the location of your cue/bin pair (both must be present in the *same* directory), and run, for example:

```
cdemu load 0 /home/mike/isos/Timeshock.cue
```

To check that it has loaded, run `cdemu status`, which will return:

```
Devices' status:
DEV   LOADED     FILENAME
0     1          /home/mike/DOS/TIMES/Timeshock.cue
1     0
```

To see the device allocation, enter `cdemu device-mapping`:

```
Device mapping:
DEV   SCSI CD-ROM     SCSI generic   
0     /dev/sr2        /dev/sg4       
1     /dev/sr3        /dev/sg5
```

You can also `cd` to `/media` and run `ls` to show the new entry:

```
cdrom  floppy  floppy0  ISOimage  Timeshock  ZEN STONE
```

Strangely enough, I still had to click to mount them in my file manager (Thunar).

You can unload the image pair by specifying the same device (`0`) used when loading the pair:

```
cdemu unload 0
```

If any errors occur, or you can't load or unload your images, just logout and login again.

---

Side Note: I was able to run `Timeshock` (a Pinball game) in `Wine` as the image mounted by `cdemu` was seen in `Wine` as `H: /media/Timeshock`. (The game had been previously installed in `Wine`) Some games, however, may require the disk to be assigned a `D:` drive letter in `Wine`.

You can also use `cdemu` for many other things than just mounting bin/cue pairs, and it may be very useful to anyone who has specific needs to emulate drives or to mount more unusual image types. More information is available at the [official site](http://cdemu.sourceforge.net/), which details the options available.

Comment: the most advanced and efficently solution, a daemon tools equivalent for linux.

Comment: Thanks! This solution also worked with an audio `CDImage.cue` and `CDImage.wav` I had. I could then extract it with `Sound Juicer` to flac files