# Can I test a cue/bin image without burning a CD?

Tags: mount, cd, brasero, cd-image

Can I test an audio CD created with Brasero (cue/bin files) in Ubuntu 16.04 without burning a CD? I would like to check that titles and other metadata are correct on the image.

Comment: It seems that the [gCDEmu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4158/how-do-i-mount-cue-file) could help. But i did not yet reach my goal ... Even if i use the gCDEmu to mount the cd audio bin/cue created by brasero, the titles and artists are not displayed by Parole app and seems to miss.

Comment: Looks like MPlayer should be able to play these files at least from the commandline with the following syntax: `mplayer cue://file[:track] [options]`. Interesting to see if SMPlayer (Mplayer frontend) can also do this with a gui...

Comment: Mplayer does not succeed at reading the cue file. I get an error: `No stream found to handle url cue://x.cue:1`  with a message ` Error reading from x.cue` but it has found the cue file because it displays the name of the good bin file.

Comment: `qmmp x.cue` display the titles but it is unable to play audio... It seems that it uses mplayer to play cue file and there is also an error while reading the cue file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to play an audio CD rip (from Nero, many many years ago) with this:

`mplayer -demuxer rawaudio my_audio_cd_rip.nrg`

or

`mpv -demuxer=rawaudio my_audio_cd_rip.nrg`

or (after changing the file extension)

`play -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 2 -L my_audio_cd_rip.cdda`

and to convert it to an MP3:

`sox -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 2 -L my_audio_cd_rip.cdda -C 320 my_audio_cd_rip.mp3`